# How to use Background gradient on a selection of rows

Tags: pandas, background, format

I want to apply a background gradient to a subset of a database rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)*50})

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4)*50, columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
df.style.background_gradient(axis=1)
```

I got this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfQPU.png)

I want to achieve this: only the last 2 rows get the gradient applied to

Answer (score 2):

[`background_gradient`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html) accepts a `subset` parameter :

```
df.style.background_gradient(axis=1, subset=pd.IndexSlice[len(df)-2:])
```

Output :

[image]